# How to auto suggest a user if a user types adjectives?

Tags: search, autosuggest

Hi I'm building a search functionality I have a product table which is below

```
     id      name
    -----------------
     1       Jeans
     2       T-shirt
     3       Shirt
     4       bla
     5       many more
```

If a user types adjectives like *stylist* or *super cool* or *damm anything* what is the best approach to show suggestions like

```
         stylist |
        ----------------------------
         stylist jeans
         stylist shirts
         bla bla...
```

My approach was let user type anything then i'll append stylist with *jeans* or *shirt* and show it to user

but a user can type anything e.g *yuiyuiy678* in this nothing has to be shown to user

any idea !!